# Mongo set intersection on single field which is a 2d array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, set, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have in mongo, documents of the following structure. I want to get all the common dates for children within a parent.

```js
{"parent": 1, "child": "a", "date": "2016-02-01"},
{"parent": 1, "child": "a", "date": "2016-02-02"},
{"parent": 1, "child": "a", "date": "2016-02-03"},
{"parent": 1, "child": "b", "date": "2016-02-01"},
{"parent": 1, "child": "b", "date": "2016-02-03"},
{"parent": 2, "child": "a", "date": "2016-02-02"},
{"parent": 2, "child": "a", "date": "2016-02-03"},
{"parent": 2, "child": "b", "date": "2016-02-01"},
{"parent": 2, "child": "b", "date": "2016-02-02"}
```

For this I have used aggregation framework with the following pipeline to get an array of date arrays.

```js
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            parent: "$parent",
            child: "$child"
        },
        dates: {
            $push: "$date"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.parent",
        dates: {
            $push: "$dates"
        }
    }
}
```

The output comes out as:

```js
[ 
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "dates" : [ 
            [ 
                "2016-02-01", 
                "2016-02-03"
            ], 
            [ 
                "2016-02-01", 
                "2016-02-02", 
                "2016-02-03"
            ]
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "dates" : [ 
            [ 
                "2016-02-01", 
                "2016-02-02"
            ], 
            [ 
                "2016-02-02", 
                "2016-02-03"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

I now want to get all the common dates within the 2d arrays per document, and I tried adding a `$projection` stage with `$setIntersection`. But from what I understand, `$setIntersection` needs an array of well defined fields or arrays - using `$setIntersection: "$dates"` does not work as expected.

Any help is appreciated!

Additional info: the number of child types is variable

Expected output:

```
[ 
    {
        "_id" : 1.0000000000000000,
        "dates" : [
            "2016-02-01", 
            "2016-02-03"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 2.0000000000000000,
        "dates" : [ 
            "2016-02-02"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the expected output documents as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well with MongoDB 3.2 you could use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to get each element of the two dimensions and feed that to [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "parent": "$parent",
            "child": "$child"
        },
        "dates": { "$push": "$date" }
    }}, 
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.parent",
        "dates": { "$push": "$dates" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "dates": {
            "$setIntersection": [
                { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$dates", 0 ] },
                { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$dates", 1 ] }
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

But really, the particular problem you are looking at can be solved in a much more simplified way. Basically all you need to do is count the child occurances per date on the parent. Anything more than one indicates there are two or more children sharing the date:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "parent": "$parent",
            "date": "$date"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.parent",
        "dates": { "$push": "$_id.date" }
    }}
])
```

So there is no reason to compare arrays, as a simple count of grouped elements tells you what the "set intersection" would be.

And that same principle works with every MongoDB version from where the aggregation framework was introduced.

Both give you the same result:

```js
{ "_id" : 1, "dates" : [ "2016-02-03", "2016-02-01" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "dates" : [ "2016-02-02" ] }
```

Also noting that "sets" are not considered to be ordered, and neither is the order of keys emitted from `$group`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first one I could not use, as the number of array elements are not defined, there can be multiple children. The second one was a mind opener! This is so simple, and is exactly what I needed! I don't know what thought track I was thinking in :)

Comment: @arawind The real point was that the second process is equal to what you are doing by looking at it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

What can be done here is count the number of children of a parent and count the number of dates for each child of a parent.

And then get all the dates where number of dates is equal to the number of children of a parent, that will give the expected output.

Here is what I tried, but possibly there can be better solution.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                parent: "$parent",
                child: "$child"
            },
            dates: {
                $push: "$date"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.parent",
            total_children: {$sum : 1},
            dates: {
                $push: "$dates"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$dates"
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$dates"
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : {
                parent : "$_id",
                dates : "$dates"
            },
            total_children : {$first : "$total_children"},
            total_dates : {$sum : 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            _id : 1,
            tempEq : {$eq : ["$total_children", "$total_dates"]}
        }
    },
    {
        $match : {'tempEq' : true}
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : '$_id.parent',
            dates : {$addToSet : "$_id.dates"}
        }
    }
])
```

And this gives following output:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "dates" : [ "2016-02-01", "2016-02-03" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "dates" : [ "2016-02-02" ] }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks but the accepted answer is a lot simpler :)

Comment: Welcome.. In my case I have assumed you might have more than 2 children for the parent.  :)

Comment: You did assume right, and the second half of the accepted answer is what answers it. If I'm not wrong, you're following a similar approach? And probably most of your aggregation stages can be merged into one..